# Laravel IIS HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I'm trying to deploy my laravel application on windows server 2012 R2 but I get this error when trying to access the site.

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6by27.png)

Here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you installed PHP on the server? Could you update the question with the relevant PHP configuration details, like if you're using FastCGI or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Your Directory Path should be :

`c:/inetpub/wwwroot/sitename/public`

Instead of this :

`c:/inetpub/wwwroot/sitename`

Comment: are you using `IIS 7`

Comment: How do I check version? Sorry, it's my first time using IIS

Comment: I got it. I'm using 8.5

Comment: modify this line like this - `<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />`

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: put url root IIS on public folder through Right clic on website you want install laravel on IIS interface and "Manage WebSite" > "Advanced Settings" and change the directory for public like root website

Comment: Give the rights to write for 2 users : Users ou IIS_IUSRS for 3 directories :

/vendor
/storage
/bootstrat/cache

Comment: Go to this link - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/iis-8-laravel-webconfig

Comment: If you are using first time IIS. May it is iis configure problem.

Comment: if above solution not work then tell me I will help you

Comment: definitely it is your IIS problem.

Comment: Please clarify the Users ou IIS_IUSRS part. Should I give read/write permission to Users and IIS_IUSRS?

Comment: which is your os?

Comment: Could you help me find out?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Working on a server

Comment: Go to link for configure IIS : http://thesolving.com/server-room/how-to-install-and-configure-iis-on-windows-server-2012-r2/